# I'm unable to access the table values as it is not having a table tag

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

Tables usually have a  tag but this table is defined in the  class and it also has a container
This is the website: https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/admin/viewJobTitleList

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K7gg.png)

```
List<WebElement> jobs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'app\']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]"));
    for(int i=0;i<jobs.size();i++){
            System.out.println(jobs.get(i).getText());
        }
    }
```

This above code is not showing error as well as not working ,please tell me whats wrong

Comment: Manual steps to reach the page with the table?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium no its automation the above is a code snippet only of this part

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that your locator was not correct. It found no elements when I tried it.

Switch to a CSS selector, `div.oxd-table-body > div > div > div:nth-of-type(2)` and it should work just fine.

```
List<WebElement> jobs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.oxd-table-body > div > div > div:nth-of-type(2)"));
for(int i = 0; i < jobs.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(jobs.get(i).getText());
    }
}
```

---

NOTE: You can test locators in the dev tools console of the browser. Just run `$$()` for CSS selectors and `$x()` for XPath. For example, the locator above would be

```
$$("div.oxd-table-body > div > div > div:nth-of-type(2)")
```

and it returns 25 elements on the page.